# 'We the commuter' vs 'We the commuters'

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

On a poster, would 'We the commuter' or 'We the commuters' be more correct?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the message is from the Queen.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow that something can have versions that are gradeable ("more correct") then it seems to be an opinion-based question. I've not heard of more correct, only correct and incorrect.  If you're asking if "we the commuter" is incorrect, that depends on one's perspective. English allows for a lot of flexibility. It could be a play on words of "we the people" with  *commuter* being used as  a personification of the mass of commuters  standing as one. Stranger things have been done with English. Think different.

Comment: Though I've said below that 'commuters' would be more grammatically correct, the singular 'commuter' in this instance to personify and singularise the masses is actually really cool.

Answer (score 0):

It would be either **I, THE COMMUTER** or **WE, THE COMMUTERS**.

The only way **WE** would work with **COMMUTER** would be to say something like **WE, THE COMMUTER COMMUNITY.**

Answer (score -1):

'Commuters' is plural form, it should be used with 'We'.

Answer (score -1):

- Commuter (noun, s.)

"As a regular commuter, I know the bus routes around here pretty well."

"I, the commuter, demand better services for my money."

- Commuters (noun, pl.)

"A train packed with commuters"

"We the commuters, feel that travel-services in the UK need to rethink their pricing policies."

Edit: I'm also tempted to suggest an apostrophe to indicate the possessive noun in **Commuters' Protest**.